# How Do I Get ICACLS to Report Numeric SIDs

Tags: acl

I type:

```
ICACLS filename
```

Results are:

```
filename   No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
(R,W)
           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
           BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
```

I would like it to report the actual SIDs, especially the one "No mapping between ...".  Is that possible with ICACLS?  And if not, what tool will do this?

(Update 2/22/2012) I know about the "ICACLS filename /save saveFile" syntax, but having to open an intermediate file adds complexity to writing scripts.  I would prefer console output.  The output stored in "saveFile" looks like this...

```
 filename
 D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x12008f;;;S-1-5-83-1-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `ICACLS filename /SAVE con:` to send the output to the console. But I suspect that format may still not quite be what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for (6 years ago).  I hope it helps someone else, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the absense of any other answers, I will say that the only way is to use the "ICACLS filename /SAVE output_file" syntax.  Not what I wanted.